# how to use osmdroid's OSM MAP Tile Packager

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I want to use the included tile packager from [osmdroid's solution](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) to use maps offline since [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) didn't work for me (I want 16x zoom levels which is not possible using this tool).

The instructions say that should run a `.jar` file using a command line, but there are no `.jar` files in the package and there are only source code files which when I run with netbeans IDE, gives me an error about unresolved dependency issues.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

The answer given here didn't work for me as the .jar file always gave me a manifest (main class) error. So what I ended up doing was:

1. Download the project from [github](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid)
2. run a 'gradle build' in the top folder (you can comment out the included libraries in the settings.gradle file if there is any problem with the Android SDK and you only need to use the tile packager)
3. run a 'gradle run' in the OSMMapTilePackager folder
4. by now gradle should have generated the following folder: OSMMapTilePackager/build/distributions/ and inside that folder you should have a zip file called something like OSMMapTilePackager-5.6-SNAPSHOT.zip. Unzip it
5. Go to the bin folder and run ./OSMMapTilePackager -gui

A window should have opened asking you for the parameters to download the tiles.

Got the procedure from this [issue discussion](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/300).

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `gradle compileJava` in `OSMMapTilePackager` directory. The jar should be in the `tagret` directory.

Comment: I am new to gradle.but when I use `gradle tasks` in command line, there's no such action as `compile java` in the tasks

Comment: ok I was using gradle wrong. but now that I actually called `gradle compilejava` I am getting the following error: ` Cannot resolve external dependency org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:0.6 because no repositories are defined`

Comment: try to add
 `repositories {
    jcenter()
}` to the `build.gradle`

Comment: ok I finally made java compile work.but it didn't make any jar executeables. All there is, is some `.class` files and other stuff.but there are no .jar files

Comment: @user2078785, call `gradle jar`, the jar should be in the `OSMMapTilePackager/build/libs/`